# C# - How to initialize multiple variables in a loop

Tags: c#, vba

I figured out how to do this with VBA.

```
Dim variable(1 To 10) As Variant
```

I am having a tough time figuring out how to do this with C#.  Here is what I have that does not work:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
{
    List<List<string>> row(y) = new List<List<string>>();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `row(y)`?

Comment: var variable = object[10];

Comment: `var variable = new object[10];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your purpose correctly, you're trying to do this:

```
List<List<string>> row = new List<List<string>>(10);
for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
{
    row.Add(new List<string>());
}
```

This will create a list of 10 `List<string>` objects and initialize each element with a new `List<string>` object.

### Edit

After seeing your latest comment, you need this:

```
var rows = new List<List<string>>[10];
for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
{
    rows[y] = new List<List<string>>();
}
```

Comment: You have to do `row.Add(new List<string>());`.

Comment: Close.  I guess I would like to create:
List<List<string>> row1 = new List<List<string>>();
List<List<string>> row2 = new List<List<string>>();
List<List<string>> row3 = new List<List<string>>();
etc..

Comment: @juharr: Thanks. Indeed.

Comment: @oso0690 Wait is that what the VBA code does, create 10 variables named `variable1` to `variable10`?

Comment: If I remember correctly, I believe so.  I would just like to create 10 List<List<string>>'s with indexing of the variable.

Comment: @oso0690: My code would do exactly that. But the only you wrote in comments is entirely different thing. It is not using indexes anywhere.

Comment: @oso0690 No, I just checked.  That VBA code is creating an array you would do stuff like `variable(1)` which is how VBA does arrays.  I guess you want a `List<List<string>>[10]`, but that seems strange.  Maybe you need to tell us exactly how you plan to use your data type.

Comment: Yes, I want something like List<List<string>>[10] but I can't get the syntax down.  Ultimately, I would like to have a y amount of List<List<string>>'s.  The naming of the variables can be row1, row2, row3, or row(1), row(2), row(3), etc.  I just need a way of looping through the creation of multiple List<List<string>>'s.

Comment: That's it!  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways this can be done, using a List of `List<string>` :

```
List<List<string>> list = new List<List<string>>();
for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
{
    list.Add(new List<string>());
}
```

Using an array of `List<string>`

```
List<string>[] array = new List<string>[10];
for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
{
    array[y] = new List<string>();
}
```